# Conditional probability rules with set $P(A \cup B\mid C) = P(A\mid C) + P(B\mid C) - P(A\cap B\mid C)$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am learning about conditional properties for probability. And I am wondering about one particular rule for three events A, B, C where the probability of event C Is greater than 0.

Can someone explain this rule perhaps via a Venn diagram?

I tried to draw it but the LHS does not seem to match RHS.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: use backslashes rather then forward slashes for \cup and \cap... I fixed it for you.

Comment: Can you do the corresponding thing without the "$\;|C$" in it?

Comment: A P is missing on the left-hand side of your equation!

Comment: You have included an image of your "attempt" using venn diagrams.  It appears that you don't know what $\mid$ represents here.  Can you tell us what you think $P(A\cup B\mid C)$ actually means?

Comment: It *looks* like you think $P(A\cup B\mid C)$ is representing $P(A\cup (B\cap C))$.  It does not.

Answer (score 1):

$P(A\cup B\mid C) = \dfrac{P((A\cup B)\cap C)}{P(C)} = \dfrac{P((A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C))}{P(C)}$

Now, apply inclusion-exclusion to the numerator using the events $A\cap C$ and $B\cap C$ (*instead of how they normally appear in inclusion exclusion as $A$ and $B$*)

$=\dfrac{P(A\cap C)+P(B\cap C)-P(A\cap C\cap B\cap C)}{P(C)}$

This all separates and simplifies as $=P(A\mid C)+P(B\mid C)-P(A\cap B\mid C)$

---

If you *insist* on using venn diagrams, then due to the fact that we are using conditional probabilities conditioned on $C$, you should ignore everything outside of $C$.

The ratio of area that is blue compared to the size of the circle for $C$ here, $P(A\cup B\mid C)$:

[image]

Is equal to the sum of the blue areas here, $P(A\mid C)$:

[image]

and here, $P(B\mid C)$:

[image]

Except that by adding those areas we added the bit in the middle, $P(A\cap B\mid C)$, too much so to correct that we subtract by that amount again after the fact to fix.

Answer (score 0):

$A \cap C$ includes a copy of $A \cap B \cap C$.  $B \cap C$ *also* includes a copy of $A \cap B \cap C$.  To not double count the probability contribution from $A \cap B \cap C$, you must subtract one of the two copies of contributions from $A \cap B \cap C$ from $P(A \mid C) + P(B \mid C)$.